# Fedora 36 KDE Plasma spin monitor not receiving signal after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: fedora, drivers, kde, nvidia, plasma

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-36-linux/) on how to install nvidia drivers on Fedroa 36. Specifically, I installed `akmod-nvidia` and `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda`. When I reboot my machine, my monitor doesn't receive a signal and I can't interact with the computer.

If I start the OS in text mode by appending a 3 at the end of the `linux` line in GRUB, the monitor detects it fine. If I run `nvidia-smi`, I get the expected output showing information about my graphics card.

What am I doing wrong? Also, let me know if there is more information I can provide in my questiojn and I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was cased by having the two GTX 1080 TI cards connected to each other with a SLI bridge. When I removed the SLI bridge, I was able to boot the system up with the drivers.